# apt-get in LXC container is very slow on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: apt, performance, lxc, zfs

I haven't had much luck in finding out the source of the issue, whether this "issue" is simply a limitation of LXC or zfs, or whether this issue is specific to Ubuntu.

The issue is quite simply that `apt-get` is very slow when run inside a container.

`apt-get` hangs for about 30 seconds when reading package lists (after I've run `apt-get update` for example)

```
Reading package lists... 99%
```

It also hangs when installing new software. Installing `strace` for example, it hangs here:

```
Setting up strace (4.5.20-2.3ubuntu1) ...
```

I'm using the daily build of lxc with zfs backing store.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I have the same problems and it's a really weird one.

Comment: If you don't want to turn off sync for your entire zfs pool, you can use eatmydata.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7238/how-to-make-dpkg-faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's solution removed from the question:

> I've done some more digging, and have found a solution with the help of a colleague.
>
> First, I used `strace` to figure out where it was hanging:
>
> ```
> strace apt-get update
> ```
>
> And noticed it was hanging on
>
> ```
> msync(0x7f02a57b1000, 37879664, MS_SYNC ...
> ```
>
> Research suggested this was related to disk I/O.
>
> So I installed and ran `iostat`:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install sysstat
> sudo iostat -x 1
> ```
>
> Disk util was at about 90%. This confirmed disk I/O bottleneck.
>
> My colleague suggested I try switching off synchronous file syncing for ZFS:
>
> ```
> zfs set sync=disabled pool/fs
> ```
>
> And this solved my issues!
>
> Whether or not this is a bug or a feature is still up for debate, so I'll leave this issue unanswered for a couple of days.